# What Linux has BSD-ports like package management?

Tags: package-management, distribution-choice

Looking for Linux server distro (not need X-windows and such), what downloads source code to the "right" place and compiles packages - e.g. a distribution that uses something like BSD-ports system.

I'm tired with Ubuntu (and such) when need some header files from some package's sources and searching how to get & install sources...

It is not a critique of Ubuntu and such, only I'm coming from the BSD world and looking for a Linux that is as easy and as simple as BSD.

Any recommendations for Linux that installs packages with their sources and header files?

Comment: I'd be interested to hear a concrete case here. What software did you try to install on Ubuntu that required that you chase down some random header to install, which installed out of the box on a BSD machine? How do you tie that success to the nature of Ports? It seems to me that if Ports found the right dependency and built it first, that the same could be done with Ubuntu. I suspect you are comparing a mix of tarballs and DEBs on Ubuntu to a pure Ports experience, which isn't apples-to-apples. Keep in mind that FreeBSD is moving to `pkgng`, which is more like `apt-get` than Ports.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The closest to BSD ports is Gentoo Linux's Portage: http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Portage

P.S. I have positive experience with building Debian/Ubuntu packages from source, but that's not your main question, so I'm not going to get into details.

Comment: Arch Linux also has a ports-like system, the [Arch Build System](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_Build_System) and the [Arch User Repository](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_User_Repository). It's a very simple system, especially compared to building packages for Debian/Ubuntu.